# Minimize ||Ax|| on the non negative region of the unit sphere: ||x|| = 1, x ≥ 0

Tags: python, linear-algebra, linear-programming, scipy-optimize, svd

Having a non-square matrix A, I need to find the direction (versor) x ≥ 0 which is "most perpendicular" to all rows of A (in a least sum of squares sense).

I tried with SVD: if A = U Σ V*, the "most perpendicular" vector is the last column in V. But it is not guaranteed to be ≥ 0, so I need to check other vectors in V, to see if I can combine them s.t. the result is ≥ 0. I couldn't find a simple method.

I read the documentation of the linear least-square `scipy.optimize` functions (and `scipy.optimize.linprog`), but I don't know how to search on the unit sphere ||x|| = 1. I know I can use the generic `scipy.optimize.minimize`, but I was wondering if there exists a more adequate approach (adapted to the linear nature of Ax).

I am looking for a solution in Python (numpy, scipy etc.). Optimized for speed. It should work for both tall and fat matrices A (overdetermined and underdetermined systems).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This seems more fit for the [math stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @gspr I came here from there. :)

Comment: What is your objection to using `scipy.optimize.minimize`? Minimize a cost function e.g. `norm(A @ x/norm(x)) + lambda_ * norm(x)`, with some arbitrary penalty factor `lambda_` for `x` not being norm 1. Use bounds `((0, None),) * m`.

Comment: @PierreD I was hoping to find an algorithm that takes advantage of the linear nature of the cost function Ax. Now I realize it is not linear, because the cost function is actually ||Ax||, which is not linear in x. I implemented it with `scipy.optimize.minimize` plus an equality constraint `numpy.linalg.norm(x) - 1 = 0`, plus bounds. It works, but I was wondering if there existed a faster solution. I guess there isn't.

Comment: If you are lucky, the last column of `V` is either `V >= 0` of `V <= 0`. But the problem is, when signs of its components are mixed, then, as you noted, you need to "blend in" other columns (the norm of the mixing coefficients is 1). It is often the case, but not always, that the resulting `x` has one or more components at 0, and the others are relatively close to the values of that last vector, which makes it understandable that you'd want to reuse SVD's `V` vector. But finding the mixing parameters is itself another optimization.

Comment: Can you give the Python code that uses `minimize`? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp for example lets you provide `eqcons`, a list of functions representing equality constraints but I'm not sure whether I understand your verbal description accurately enough to guess whether it'd be faster than `minimize` :)

Comment: @AhmedFasih This is what I used, the SLSQP solver. Here's an example I prepared: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xc_tMXXoD-RKL-vz4KwTWkrzoSTjL7DF?usp=sharing